# 4 input & Dynamically change transform

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

I'm trying to make a transform generator.

Users will constantly update this, but without success. Because when I use jquery element.css('transform', .... it changes it to singleton. But, I can't change other elements.

HTML

```
<p>ROTATE X</p>
 <input class="inputrange" name="transformRx" type="range">
<p>ROTATE Y</p>
 <input class="inputrange" name="transformRy" type="range">
<p>SKEW Y</p>
 <input class="inputrange" name="transformSy" type="range">
<p>SKEW X</p>
 <input class="inputrange" name="transformSx" type="range">

<!--2-->
<p>ROTATE X</p>
<input class="inputrange2" name="transformRx" type="range">
<p>ROTATE Y</p>
<input class="inputrange2" name="transformRy" type="range">
<p>SKEW Y</p>
<input class="inputrange2" name="transformSy" type="range">
<p>SKEW X</p>
<input class="inputrange2" name="transformSx" type="range">

<div id="inputrange" class="ht" name="draggable">
  <div id="inner-inputrange"></div>
</div>

<div id="inputrange2" class="ht" name="draggable">
  <div id="inner-inputrange2"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('input[type="range"]').on('input change', function(){
switch (this.name){
case "transformRx":
      calculateMatrix(this.className, this.value, null, null, null)
break;
case "transformRy":
  calculateMatrix(this.className, null, this.value, null, null)
  break;
case "transformSy":
  calculateMatrix(this.className, null, null, this.value, null)
  break;
case "transformSx":
  calculateMatrix(this.className, null, null, null, this.value)
  break;
}})

function calculateMatrix(elName, rotateX, rotateY, skewY, skewX) {
if (elName != "undefined") {
$('#'+elName).css('transform', ''rotateX('+rotateX+'deg) rotateY('+rotateY+'deg) skewX('+skewX+'deg) skewY('+skewY+'deg)')
}
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/36wcu958/5/)

I'm just trying to ask a question and had to make a bunch of edits to post a question.

There may be things I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want?

you cant add multiple transform in an element so you have to create all the transformation in one string.

```js
var transform = [];

function updateCss(This) {
  // console.log(This);
  const type = $(This).data("type");
  const end = $(This).data("end");
  const value = $(This).val();
  let transform_string = "";
  transform[type] = `${type}(${value}${end})`;

  Object.keys(transform).forEach((item, index, array) => {
    transform_string += transform[item];
  });
  $('#inputrange').css("transform",transform_string);
}
```

```css
#inputrange{
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: blue;
}

#inner-inputrange{
  width: 5rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: purple;
}
#inputrange2{
  margin-top: 5rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: blue;
}

#inner-inputrange2{
  width: 5rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>ROTATE X</p>
 <input class="inputrange"data-type="rotateX" data-end="deg" onchange="updateCss(this)" name="transformRx" type="range">
<p>ROTATE Y</p>
 <input class="inputrange" data-type="rotateY" name="rotateY" data-end="deg" 
        onchange="updateCss(this)" type="range">
<p>SKEW Y</p>
 <input class="inputrange"
        data-type="skewY"
        data-end="deg" 
        onchange="updateCss(this)"
        name="transformSy" type="range">
<p>SKEW X</p>
 <input class="inputrange" name="transformSx"
         data-type="skewX"
        data-end="deg" 
        onchange="updateCss(this)"
        type="range">

<div id="inputrange" class="ht" name="draggable">
  <div id="inner-inputrange"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with what I want to do.
If you click the JSFIDDLE link, you'll know what I mean, man.

Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: ill look and update my answer .